# Firewire cable disconnected during Migration; process interrupted

Tags: macbook-pro, firewire, migration-assistant

this is my first post here but it seems like a helpful place. I got a used 2010 MacBook pro last weekend, and have had a hell of a time trying to transfer data from my older MBP via Migration Assistant and Firewire. On the first attempt, I left the two computers running overnight, and my roommate unplugged the power adapter from the old one so that it died before the transfer finished.

I finally got around to trying again last night, and this hasn't gone well either. I created a new user account, went to Migration Assistant, and chose to overwrite the botched user account that had been mostly transferred from my old computer. I got to 47 minutes left, and accidentally unplugged the firewire cable! Needless to say, very frustrated with myself. I plugged it back in and waited for the drive to show back up on the desktop, but it's now been stuck on 47 minutes for a couple of hours. What should I do? Do I really have to start over completely yet again? Any help would be greatly appreciated.